# dbplyr ambiguous column name

Tags: r, odbc, tidyverse, dbplyr

I'm joining two relatively simple tables using `ODBC` and `dbplyr`.  However, I'm getting an error on my join key, it's throwing up an `ambiguous column name error`.  This doesn't happen normally with dplyr joins, and I don't know how to use like an `a.key = b.key`, using `dbplyr`.

```
Error: nanodbc/nanodbc.cpp:1655: 42000: [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Ambiguous column name 'Calendar_key'.  [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Statement(s) could not be prepared. 
<SQL> 'SELECT "Calendar_key", "Organization_key", "Product_Key", "Promotion_Key", "Shift_Key", "ETL_source_system_key", "Pack_Size", "Qty_Sold", "Inv_Unit_Qty", "Extended_Cost", "Extended_Purchase_Rebate", "Extended_Sales_Rebate", "Extended_Sales", "Ent_Source_Hdr_Key", "Ent_Source_Dtl_Key", "Day_Date", "Day_Of_Week_ID", "Day_Of_Week", "Holiday", "Type_Of_Day", "Calendar_Month_No", "Calendar_Month_Name", "Calendar_Qtr_No", "Calendar_Qtr_Desc", "Calendar_Year", "Fiscal_Week", "Fiscal_Period_No", "Fiscal_Period_Desc", "Fiscal_Year"
FROM "Item_Sales_Fact" AS "LHS"
LEFT JOIN "calendar" AS "RHS"
ON ("LHS"."Calendar_key" = "RHS"."calendar_key")
```

This is the code block below: My connection is called con

```
con <- dbConnect(odbc(),
                 Driver = "SQL Server",
                 Server = "192.168.139.1",
                 Database = "pdi_warehouse_2304_01",
                 UID = XXXX,
                 PWD = XXXX,
                 Port = 1433)

item.sales <- tbl(con, "Item_Sales_Fact")
calendar <- tbl(con, "calendar")
organization <- tbl(con, "Organization")

test.df <- item.sales %>%
  left_join(calendar, by = c("Calendar_key" = "calendar_key")) %>%
  collect()
```

Comment: Are the column names correct

Comment: Yes, there are no shared column names except for those two, and they've got that weird capital/lowercase thing going on.

Comment: I wonder if the error is because of `key` substring in the column name

Comment: You wouldn't think so, but the question would be how to correct for it?  I can't change the column names in the table.

Answer (score 1):

The `SQL` generated by `dbplyr` isn't correct as `Calendar_key` can either come from `RHS` or `LHS` because `SQL` isn't case sensitive and contrary to R doesn't make a distinction between `Calendar_key` and `calendar_key`:

```
SELECT "Calendar_key", ...
```

The problem seems to come from the fact that although `SQL` isn't case sensitive, `SQL Server` handles case sensitive column names.

A workaround is to rename one of the two keys to obtain exactly the same case sensitive names:

```
item.sales <- tbl(con, "Item_Sales_Fact")
calendar <- tbl(con, "calendar") %>% rename(Calendar_key = calendar_key)

test.df <- item.sales %>%
  left_join(calendar, by = c("Calendar_key" = "Calendar_key")) %>%
  collect()
```

Comment: @Jeremy R. Johnson, did it answer your question?